# How do I update from 8.4.5 to 8.5.0?

Tags: 8, updating

[image]I am trying to update Drupal core using Composer, but I am not able of doing it. I have followed a few blog posts, but nothing worked for me. This is the output of `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`.
[image]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: have you removed the `"replace": {   "drupal/core": "^8.x" }, ` and add `"drupal/core": "~8.5"` in require part of `composer.json` file then perform steps as described in @Jdrupal answer below

Comment: @RazeemAhmad yes as it can be clearly seen in my screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing files like `composer.json`

I had the same error "Nothing to install or update".

Here is what I’ve done and it worked :

In composer.json :

add

```
"require": {
        ---
        "drupal/core": "~8.5"
    },
```

remove if you have this :

```
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.x"
},
```

delete `vendor` folder

delete `composer.lock` file

Then `composer update --with-dependencies`

Comment: I have posted my JSON file screenshot... I have tried your ^8.x way but composer doesn't recognize it well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I explicitly had to include `webflo/drupal-core-require-dev` in the update statement, as documented on the [Drupal Composer template project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project#user-content-updating-drupal-core)

```
composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev symfony/* --with-dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently going from 8.4.8 - 8.6.10
After successfully running these commands below from the posts above:

1. change in composer.json:

   "require": {

   ```
     "drupal/core": "~8.6.10"
   ```

   },
2. deleted vendor folder
3. deleted composer.lock file
4. Ran in terminal:

composer update --with-dependencies

There were no errors in the terminal - however I now had the Drupal WSOD. Checking the log files showed that there were now 2 core folders : one one in the root and one in vendor/Drupal/.

In the error.log I have the following error:

Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 65

I don't believe this is a valid upgrade path.

It is currently recommended to use composer to update Drupal projects using the following post.
https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/converting-non-composer-drupal-codebase-use-composer

================================

Update: I have got the upgrade working with the following steps:

Review all file permissions

deleted vendor folder

deleted composer.lock file

Update ownership - especially for sites/default/files

sudo chmod -R 777 sites/default/files

I then had to explicitly add various modules in use that wouldn't be installed
update required in composer.json:

"require": {

```
  "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",

  "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",

  "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*",

  "drupal/flysystem": "^1.0",

  "twistor/flysystem-stream-wrapper": "^1.0",

  "drupal/flysystem_s3": "1.x-dev",

  "drupal/feeds": "^3.0",

  "drush/drush": "^9.5"

}
```

With drush installed run the following commands:

vendor/bin/drush cr

vendor/bin/drush updb

vendor/bin/drush entup

And I now have a working Drupal site from 8.4.8 to 8.6.10!